# Adjust existing json file using python

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to programming and using Python in particular. Just been following a course for the past couple of weeks. Now i'm trying to adjust a provided json file using python.
But since i'm new to this i'm not sure what i should do, i have the following code:

```
import json

test_json = open("gras_blok.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(test_json)
test_json.close()
print(json_object)

json_object["snow"] = True
json_object["coordinates"] = {'y' : 186, 'x' : 96, 'z' : 1041}

test_json = open("gras_blok.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, test_json)
test_json.close()
```

this is currently in the Json file:

```
{"block": {"stackable": true, "luminant": false, "snow": false, "coordinates": {"y": 120, "x": 96, "z": 347}}}
```

But in this way it only adds the 2 object, how do i adjust or remove the existing ones?

Also how do i save it as a new json file, just change the name behind 'open'?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show an input example

Comment: this is currently in the Json file:
{"block": {"stackable": true, "luminant": false, "snow": false, "coordinates": {"y": 120, "x": 96, "z": 347}}}

Comment: Please always include additional information in the question itself (you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69361223/edit) questions).

Comment: My bad, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update your json file, adding, removing and adjusting values in it.

As far as I understand, the json file has the following structure:

```
{
"block": {
    "stackable": true,
    "luminant": false,
    "snow": false,
    "coordinates": {
        "y": 120,
        "x": 96,
        "z": 347
    }
}
```

}

This means that the original file has all data wrapped inside the object "block". So if you run these lines:

```
json_object["snow"] = True
json_object["coordinates"] = {'y' : 186, 'x' : 96, 'z' : 1041}
```

You are actually asking to put these values at the same level as "block".

If you want to change the values inside "block", you should write it like this:

```
json_object["block"]["snow"] = True
json_object["block"]["coordinates"] = {'y' : 186, 'x' : 96, 'z' : 1041}
```

The error you are getting is actually trough a lack of understanding on json. If you want to learn more about it, there is a good guide here:

https://realpython.com/python-json/

Comment: Thanks, allmost there i guess. Now it adjusts the value but also still adds them as well.

Comment: @LarsMedendorp if your json file has been edited prior to this, it might still have the old inserts you made. Please make sure that you are using the original file, and that you removed the old lines of code.

Comment: No worries. If my answer was a solution to your problem please accept it so others with the same issue might see it.